# Mod_security for Apache2 blocks cURL!

Tags: apache, owasp, waf, mod-security, curl

I'm trying to get my users lat. and lng. from their address using Google's geocoding API but when mod:security is enabled, it prevents it and the script times out. How can I add an exception by IP or domain for this or just remove whatever configuration that makes mod_security do this?
I am using the [OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_ModSecurity_Core_Rule_Set_Project)

UPDATE:

```
[Sun Jun 26 13:13:14 2011] [error] [client 174.252.196.188]
 ModSecurity: Unable to retrieve collection (name "ip", key "174.252.196.188_fc2ccdca4bf1fc8585b77c1444811dedd59da612").
 Use SecDataDir to define data directory first. [hostname mydomain.com"] [uri "/admin/geocoding.php"]
 [unique_id "EIpfP38AAAEAAA2eAT0AAAAK"]
```

I have added this line:

```
SecDataDir /var/log/apache/modsec_SecDataDir
```

Now, I don't get anything in the error log, but still the same behaviour!

Comment: What's in the logs for those requests?

Comment: @Bill Weiss I added the log line to the question

Answer (score 2):

If you can provide the lines in your log file showing what rule is causing the block it would be helpful.
An option would be to use [`SecRuleRemoveByID`](http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/2.5.9/modsecurity2-apache-reference.html#N10A8B) to disable the rule that is causing your block. 
Alternatively you can white list IP address using a number of different techniches which are listed [here](http://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/Mod_security)

Comment: I added the line of log file showing the event!